# Help with setting DimPlot UMAP output into a 2x3 grid in Seurat

Tags: seurat, single-cell

On my merged seurat object of 6 samples, when I use the split.by function in tandem with the Dimplot/UMAP plot, all six samples are displayed in series along a commonly labeled 'UMAP_1' x-axis in an order of (these are arbitrary for simplicity, here) Z, Y, X, C, B, A. Instead, I would like to specify these plots to output as a 2 row x 3 column arrangement ordered (1st Row) A, B, C and (2nd Row) X, Y, Z.

I'm assuming I could use something like: group_levels <- c("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y", "Z") to define the order I'd like, but I'm lost on how to get this to arrange the UMAP plots into a 2x3 grid I'd like.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: can you post the code or show with an example dataset (e.g pbmc_small in Seurat) ? I think it is a bit hard to follow in words what you need

Comment: I am sure you would prefer an answer with working code, so i encourage you to do the same here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to get this to arrange the UMAP plots into a 2x3 grid

You can use the `ncol` parameter, which will set the number of columns in the "combined plot".

And for future reference, if you get the help page of the function you are using with `?DimPlot`, you will see the `...`. This means that you can feed additional arguments to other functions that `DimPlot()` uses. Apparently,  `CombinePlots()` is used under the hood and has an `ncol` parameter.

Comment: Thank you! ncol solved my problem! Here's the code I ended up using to get the columns and samples ordered, not sure if it was the most straightforward though, but works:

object$orig.ident <- factor(x=object$orig.ident, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y", "Z"))

DimPlot(object, reduction = "umap", split.by = "orig.ident", ncol =3)